# Why does not the atime option of mount always update atime of files as expected?

Tags: mount, fstab, atime

I needed to detect read access to certain files so I needed the file system to update the [`atime`](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Global_File_System_2/s1-manage-atimeconf.html) attribute of files the usual way.

### Default mount options

In the default state the file system did not update `atime` as expected though I did not use the `noatime` option:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab | grep '/home '
# /home was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=d7e67903-f24d-45a7-be90-6a134c9c1ae9 /home         ext4    defaults      0     2

$ mount | grep '/home '
/dev/sda7 on /home type ext4 (rw)

$ cat /etc/mtab | grep '/home '
/dev/sda7 /home ext4 rw 0 0
```

The `atime` on a file was updated only sometimes. Later I realized that the file system is mounted with the new [`relatime`](http://linux.koolsolutions.com/2009/01/30/installing-linux-on-usb-part-4-noatime-and-relatime-mount-options/) option.

```
$ cat /proc/mounts | grep '/home '
/dev/sda7 /home ext4 rw,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
```

### The obvious solution does not work

So it seems that the `relatime` option is the default on Ubuntu 12.04. The solution seemed to be easy - explicitly state the non-default `atime` option:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,atime /home
```

I was suprised that the actual **`mount` options looked exactly the same** like without the `atime` option.

```
$ mount | grep '/home '
/dev/sda7 on /home type ext4 (rw)

$ cat /etc/mtab | grep '/home '
/dev/sda7 /home ext4 rw 0 0

$ cat /proc/mounts | grep '/home '
/dev/sda7 /home ext4 rw,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
```

In fact the **system was behaving exactly the same** as without the `atime` option.

### Questions

What is going on? Why cannot I simply use the `atime` option? What can I do to get the normal `atime` functionality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact there are <strike>four</strike> five `atime`-related options of `mount` in Linux:

- **`noatime`** - `atime` attribute (of both files and directories) is updated only during write access.
- **`nodiratime`** - `atime` of directories is updated only during write access, can be combined with relatime.
- **`relatime`** / **`atime`** - `atime` seems to be now alias of `relatime`. This option causes the `atime` attribute to update only if the previous `atime` is older than `mtime` or `ctime`, or the previous `atime` is over 24 hours old.
- **`strictatime`** - It was formerly called `atime` and as such was the default option. It causes the `atime` attribute to update with every file access. (accessing file data, not just the metadata/attributes)
- **`lazytime`** - Linux 4.10 added a new option: only update times (atime, mtime, ctime) on the in-memory version of the file inode. The on-disk data is updated lazily (see [`man 8 mount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/mount.8) for details).

Since Linux kernel 2.6.30 the default option is `relatime`. If you want to have the original `atime` functionality you must use the `strictatime` option. In the presented case it would be:

```
sudo mount -o remount,strictatime /home
```

### Sources

- [`stat()` - `atime` problems solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_%28system_call%29#Solutions)
- [`/etc/fstab` - common options to all file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab#Common_options_to_all_filesystems)
- [Once upon a time](http://lwn.net/Articles/244829/)