# Long Ubuntu 14.04 boot

Tags: 14.04, boot, dmesg, bootchart

The boot time in my Ubuntu is very long, its actually taking more than one minute, when Windows booting in 20 seconds. Reinstalling Ubuntu doesn`t help me.

I have Asus K52F notebook:
Intel Core i3 with integrated graphics, 4GB RAM and HDD.

Here is my dmesg: http://pastebin.com/GNKStmTR

and bootchart file: [http://i.imgur.com/o93pcqv.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVBAr.png)

Comment: Since I don't feel like grinding through the `dmesg` dump, I'll put this in a comment: The number in `[]` in the `dmesg` lines is "seconds since boot".  You can also find the same format in `/var/log/dmesg.*`

Comment: Try adding to `/etc/fstab` both [noatime and nodiratime](http://askubuntu.com/a/383402/266507) *(probably instead of `relatime` if its there)*. I don't really think you would need atime, on the other hand last time I tried it was Kubuntu installed to a usb stick, and the options *drastically* improved boot time. *(though in the case of USB stick it was probably cumulative effect of both noatime and movement /var/log to tmpfs; but I think atime takes pretty much time anyway…)*.

Comment: @Hi-Angel here is my fstab file http://pastebin.com/7DEF5j4b 
How I should change it? I am as new in Linux.

Comment: @J.Ciszewski change it [like this](http://pastebin.com/dCVwtzDQ).

Comment: @Hi-Angel this don't working for me :( still boot is more than minute

Comment: @J.Ciszewski hm, strange… Could you post dmesg now, i.e. with noatime options enabled?

Comment: @Hi-Angel yeah, here is the new dmesg http://pastebin.com/c15s87eb

Comment: @J.Ciszewski interesting. I see there was a recovery on boot, after which the filesystem was remounted, and I don't see that noatime options were in use. Can you show `mount` output?